# spark-submit how to pass --driver-class-path in cluster mode?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, kerberos

Well, using docker image i am able to access hive resources if using pyspark shell with driver-class-path :

```
$ pyspark --driver-class-path /etc/spark2/conf:/etc/hive/conf
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)
Using Python version 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019 20:35:49)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>>
>>> #declaration
... appName = "test_hive_minimal"
>>> master = "yarn"
>>>
... sc = SparkSession.builder \
...     .appName(appName) \
...     .master(master) \
...     .enableHiveSupport() \
...     .config("spark.hadoop.hive.enforce.bucketing", "True") \
...     .config("spark.hadoop.hive.support.quoted.identifiers", "none") \
...     .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "True") \
...     .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
...     .getOrCreate()
>>> sql = "show tables in user_tables"
>>> df_new = sc.sql(sql)
20/08/20 15:08:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>>> df_new.show()
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|   database|           tableName|isTemporary|
+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|user_tables|              dummyt|      false|
|user_tables|abcdefg...dummytable|      false|
```

but facing below error if using same script through spark-submit as below:

```
spark-submit --master local --deploy-mode cluster --name test_hive --executor-memory 2g --num-executors 1 -- test_hive_minimal.py --verbose

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 71, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Database 'user_tables' not found;"
```

test_hive_minimal.py is a simple script checking hive db:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

appName = "test_hive_minimal"
master = "yarn"
# Creating Spark session
sc = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .master(master) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .config("spark.hadoop.hive.enforce.bucketing", "True") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.hive.support.quoted.identifiers", "none") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "True") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
    .getOrCreate()

sql = "show tables in user_tables"
df_new = sc.sql(sql)
df_new.show()
sc.stop()
```

I tried several approaches, passing hive.metastore.uris, spark.sql.warehouse.dir as well as passing xml files as --files. Somehow my executors are not able to access the config it seems. Can anyone help with this?

UPDATE:
I was successfully able to pass hive-site.xml as --files to spark-submit in cluster mode and log shows its no longer creating local derby.db for metastore. However, now facing another issue as below:

```
20/08/21 09:59:29 INFO state.StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
20/08/21 09:59:31 INFO hive.HiveUtils: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 1.2.1 using Spark classes.
20/08/21 09:59:31 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://cluster01.cdh.com:9083
20/08/21 09:59:32 ERROR transport.TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:271)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
```

seems kerberos issue, but I already have valid kerberos token and able to access hdfs via terminal / also through spark-shell from the docker. What needs to be done here? doesnt this gets automatically provisioned by yarn when submitting on cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
**Issue was fixed after sharing vol mount on the docker container and passing keytab/principal along with hive-site.xml for accessing metastore.**

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--jars /srv/python/ext_jars/terajdbc4.jar \
--files=/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml \
--keytab /home/alias/.kt/alias.keytab \ #this is mounted and kept in docker local path 
--principal alias@realm.com.org \
--name td_to_hive_test \
--driver-cores 2 \
--driver-memory 2G \
--num-executors 44 \
--executor-cores 5 \
--executor-memory 12g \
td_to_hive_test.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u should pass the keytab in spark-submit command, this code is running via SSH ?

Comment: keytab is already set in env. and I tried passing exclusively but did not help. This is submitted from inside docker terminal like all other calls.